# Cannot install subversion ubuntu 14.04 unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04, svn

I was unable to install subversion on Ubuntu 14.04.
I am getting the error message below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install subversion
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 subversion : Depends: libsvn1 (= 1.8.8-1ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libapr1 (>= 1.4.8-2~) but it is not installable
              Depends: libaprutil1 (>= 1.2.7+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is that you don't have the latest versions of some packages. You should try updating first by running this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install subversion
```